# How to add libraries to a project from JBoss AS, since you can't use Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, classpath, project

I'm trying to test DI from a Main class, I found the following command:

> java
>   -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
>   -Djava.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
>   **-classpath
>
>   "%JBOSS_HOME%\client*;
>
>   %JBOSS_HOME%\lib*;
>
>   %JBOSS_HOME%\common\lib\jboss-ejb3-vfs-spi.jar;"**
>   bla bla bla

How can I add these libraries to the project's classpath in Eclipse. 
For JBOSS_HOME\client I can just add as an external jar **jboss-appclient.jar** since it has in the manifest all other jars in the client folder.
I can't add the jars through Maven since the jars are from the AS, and not from a repository.
I want multiple solutions on how can I add all these jars in the most elegant way. I don't want to add each individual jar as external jar.

ps: think as if you'd have to tell 100 developers to manually add all jars, this is error prone, you wouldn't want that.

ps2: I'm interested in ways of **grouping** jars together so that the import will be for only one file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, you can add the dependencies to your project build file. In the scope of the dependency, choose system. Then put in the path to that jar file. You may need to add a maven property to define your jboss_home folder so you can use it in that file box. I have projects I work with where it uses jboss jar files and we reference the jars like this.

You can also add the jboss maven repository to your maven settings file. Then you can actually pull the jars from the jboss repository when you build.

Here's what it looks like when you point to the file using the Maven Pom Editor in Eclipse.
[image]

How about creating your own manifest file and pointing to the jar files you need like this.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mypackage.MyMainClass
Class-Path: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\client\jboss-client.jar
```

Comment: I don't want to copy the jars from jboss's repository. The picture works for one jar, if I have multiple jars, should I pack them in a jar with a manifest referencing all of them.

Comment: Yeah, I think that sounds like a good solution. I know JBoss has a lot of jars setup like that. If you use the jboss-client.jar it pulls in a bunch of other jar files from jboss. That's actually a good idea I've never thought of, and it may be easy to maintain. You could have a custom jar file that you keep all of your dependency jars in, then your projects would just need to load your one custom jar.

Comment: I added another thing to my answer about maybe using a customer manifest file in your project and pointing to those jars in your class-path line. That should also work. I would still recommend letting maven handle all of you dependency files though, it's just easier to read when it's in the pom.

Comment: how can I add them automatically, because is error-prone to add them manually, you don't have any checks.

Comment: There's really no way to add them automatically unless you handle your dependencies through maven. Maven will build a manifest and add them to it automatically. Or you can create a common project that contains all of the jar dependencies and then make your project dependent on that project. I think that would pull all of those jars in then automatically. Then you could just modify the common project if you wanted to add or remove jars.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *that* error prone.

And 100 developers don't have to do it.  Have one developer do it, iron out the wrinkles, and check it into Subversion.  Then have all the developers you want check out the project.

Doesn't Eclipse have a way to point to a directory and add all the JARs it finds into CLASSPATH?  You can with IntelliJ.

If you can't work without Maven, then it's become too much of a crutch.

If Eclipse can't add app server dependencies easily, switch IDEs and use IntelliJ.

Comment: I can work with Maven, but in this case Maven isn't applicable. What you say is to create a project to keep a copy of all libraries ? I don't want to copy the libraries, I want to reference them from JBOSS (which can be installed at various locations for each developer).

Comment: Usually 3rd party JARs are packaged into an EAR or WAR, which is then deployed on JBOSS.  If you put a bunch of JARs in the JBOSS server /lib, then every project that uses that app server is forced to use them whether they want to or not.  Maybe that works if there's only one deployment on the app server, but it's potentially harmful if more than one app is housed there.